Transaction query runs for days in PostgreSQL with PGBouncer
I'm running a PostgreSQL cluster with PGBouncer and very often I see in pg_stat_activity that an app is connected to the database and stays in "idle in transaction" state for days. Obviously, this is a problem with the app. However, can this be also handled from the database side in terms of limiting the lifetime of a connection in idle state?

You want to look at the idle_in_transaction_session_timeout parameter (bit of a mouthful):
Manual

idle_in_transaction_session_timeout (integer) #


Terminate any session that has been idle (that is, waiting for a client query) within an open transaction for longer than the specified amount of time. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as milliseconds. A value of zero (the default) disables the timeout.


This option can be used to ensure that idle sessions do not hold locks for an unreasonable amount of time. Even when no significant locks are held, an open transaction prevents vacuuming away recently-dead tuples that may be visible only to this transaction; so remaining idle for a long time can contribute to table bloat. See Section 25.1 for more details.

For your transaction to last for days (default is 1 day), you probably have it set to zero - you might want to double-check as to why it was set to this? As usual, test before committing to prod!
